# Steps to Solve Crash log in iphone got from apple

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, crash, crash-reports

Hey m working on one app .. Which is already on App store .. 
And in my iTunes account i got Crash log from apple 
but i dont know how to solve this Crash log

Can any one help me how to debug this crash log ..?

**Here is my Crash Log ..**

```
Process:          [1128]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/054D107C-94F9-42F5-9E70-5B8C84C0C330/--.app/
Identifier:      --
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-11-23 10:08:21.450 +0530
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  6

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x33ba28bf __exceptionPreprocess
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x306961e5 objc_exception_throw
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33af720f -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]
3   --                      0x00032439 0x00032439
4   --                          0x00031b9f 0x00031b9f
5   --                          0x000325f7 0x000325f7
6   --                          0x00033449 0x00033449
7   --                          0x0003447f 0x0003447f
8   --                          0x00028907 0x00028907
9   Foundation                      0x31390a91 -[NSThread main]
10  Foundation                      0x314245a1 __NSThread__main__
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3759fc1d _pthread_start
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3759fad8 thread_start


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x356cd1b4 __psynch_rw_unlock + 20
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37595d8c pthread_rwlock_unlock
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x30691eac unlockForMethodLookup
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x30691806 lookUpMethod
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x30691008 objc_msgSend_uncached
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33afc42e -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:]
6   UIKit                           0x3152f780 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]
7   UIKit                           0x3152f79e -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]
8   UIKit                           0x3152f79e -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]
9   UIKit                           0x3152f79e -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]
10  UIKit                           0x315302d8 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]
11  UIKit                           0x31530184 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:]
12  UIKit                           0x3158a402 -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:]
13  UIKit                           0x3158a220 -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:toView:]
14  UIKit                           0x3157295c -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:]
15  UIKit                           0x31571f4c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded]
16  UIKit                           0x31571e0c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews]
17  UIKit                           0x31530d22 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
18  CoreFoundation                  0x33b01224 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:]
19  QuartzCore                      0x3523937a -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
20  QuartzCore                      0x35238f92 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
21  QuartzCore                      0x3523d114 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
22  QuartzCore                      0x3523ce50 CA::Transaction::commit()
23  QuartzCore                      0x352646ea CA::Transaction::flush()
24  QuartzCore                      0x352646bc +[CATransaction flush]
25  UIKit                           0x31571ba6 -[UIApplication _reportAppLaunchFinished]
26  UIKit                           0x3155f632 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:]
27  UIKit                           0x3152d91a -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:]
28  UIKit                           0x3152d3b8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
29  UIKit                           0x3152cd26 _UIApplicationHandleEvent
30  GraphicsServices                0x3826bdec PurpleEventCallback
31  CoreFoundation                  0x33b7654c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
32  CoreFoundation                  0x33b764ee __CFRunLoopDoSource1
33  CoreFoundation                  0x33b7533c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
34  CoreFoundation                  0x33af84d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
35  CoreFoundation                  0x33af839e CFRunLoopRunInMode
36  UIKit                           0x3155e450 -[UIApplication _run]
37  UIKit                           0x3155b73c UIApplicationMain
38  --                          0x0000265a 0x1000 + 5722
39  --                          0x00002624 0x1000 + 5668
```

Thanks in Advance ..

Comment: What happens when you take that crash report and drop it into your XCode organizer?  It might take a couple minutes, but I would expect that your crash log would re-symbolicate and you could find out where in your code the bogus `insertObjec:atIndex:` call happened.

Comment: can u tell me how to c this crash log in X-code directly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes xcode does not make your crash report readable (for some reason), if so you can do the following steps:

- Find the approriate archive that created this error. You can do this by going to the organizer and right clicking on the archive and do a "show in finder".
- Open the archive (show package contents) and copy the app (in Products/Applications) and the dSym (in dSyms) to a temporary folder.
- Open a terminal and go to the temporary folder.
- Open "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-arm-apple-darwin $(APPNAME).app/$(APPNAME)"
- This will give all sorts of warnings about frameworks, ignore them.
- Do: set print asm-demangle on
- And: set print symbol-filename on
- Then: p/a {address in the crash log file}

This should give you the class and the functions that is in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

First go for the Responsible Thread for the Crash. From your log it seems the Crashed Thread is 6(Crashed Thread:  6).Then you have to go for the function callback stack (have a look on the top),find out the responsible framework and its CoreFoundation and the method is [__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:].You have done something wrong here. Go and check it.